# Big Equation into several lines in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations

I have a very big equation and I tried to seperate that equation into different lines using the following code but the spacing is very big. Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to save space and reduce the bulkiness of the code ?

```
    \[
\rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau \partial_tc_i(t,x,\tau)_
=
\rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau (p_i-d_i)-  
\]

\[
 \rho \Delta y, \Delta z \Delta \tau [q_{i,x}(t,x+\Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)-q_{i,x}(t,x - \Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)]
\]

\[
-  \rho \Delta x, \Delta z \Delta  \tau [q_{i,y}(t,x,y+\Delta y/2, y, z, \tau)-q_{i,y}(t,x,y - \Delta y/2, z, z, \tau)]
\]

\[
-\rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)]
\]
```

The output of this code is as follows:
[image]

I want to reduce the spacing between the lines.

Thank you.

Comment: In general, bo not leave a blank line before or after  a  display math environment. But, in this case put them in a single displaymath environment such as `gather`.

Comment: Don't use consecutive displayed math environments; you could use instead `multline` or other of the environments provided by [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for equations in several lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use either the `gather*` or the `align*` environment. Both are provided by the `amsmath` package. In the MWE below, I use the `align*` method, taking the opportunity to break up the expression from 4 rather long lines to 7 less-long lines of math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau \partial_t c_i(t,x,\tau) 
&= \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \tau (p_i-d_i)  \\
&- \rho \Delta y, \Delta z \Delta \tau [q_{i,x}(t,x+\Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)\\
&\qquad - q_{i,x}(t,x - \Delta x/2, y, z, \tau)]\\
&- \rho \Delta x, \Delta z \Delta  \tau [q_{i,y}(t,x,y+\Delta y/2, y, z, \tau)\\
&\qquad - q_{i,y}(t,x,y - \Delta y/2, z, z, \tau)]\\
&- \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta \tau[q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z+\Delta z/2, \tau) \\
&\qquad - q_{i,z}(t,x,y,z-\Delta z/2, \tau)]
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```